# Code for FCM causing 500 internal error in Next.js App

Tags: next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, next.js13

I am trying to set up push notifications in my Next.js app using Firebase Cloud Messaging. However, when I added the following code in my client component, it causes a 500 internal error. Any idea why this is happening?

This is the code that causes the 500 error to occur.

```
    const { fcmToken, notificationPermissionStatus } = useFcmToken();
    // Use the token as needed
    fcmToken && console.log('FCM token:', fcmToken);
  
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    useEffect(() => {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        const messaging = getMessaging(app);
        const unsubscribe = onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
          console.log('Foreground push notification received:', payload);
          // Handle the received push notification while the app is in the foreground
          // You can display a notification or update the UI based on the payload
        });
        return () => {
          unsubscribe(); // Unsubscribe from the onMessage event
        };
      }
    }, []);(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNcqu.png)
```

[[image]]

This is my useFcmToken custom hook.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getMessaging, getToken } from 'firebase/messaging';
import app from '@/db/firebase';

const useFcmToken = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const [notificationPermissionStatus, setNotificationPermissionStatus] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useFcmToken called")
    const retrieveToken = async () => {
      try {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
          const messaging = getMessaging(app);
            console.log("messaging", messaging)
          // Retrieve the notification permission status
          const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
          setNotificationPermissionStatus(permission);
            console.log("permission", permission)
          // Check if permission is granted before retrieving the token
          if (permission === 'granted') {
            const currentToken = await getToken(messaging, {
              vapidKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_VAPID_KEY,
            });
            if (currentToken) {
              setToken(currentToken);
            } else {
              console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token:', error);
      }
    };

    retrieveToken();
  }, []);

  return { fcmToken: token, notificationPermissionStatus };
};

export default useFcmToken;
```

I commented out the code and the 500 internal error disappeared but I need that to call my custom hook to get the FCM token.

Comment: Well, then attach a debugger at the backend and check what exactly the error is ...